# Why is convergence of measures tested against functions?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

This question is to help my intuition. Why do we test the convergence of measures against different classes of functions and not use definitions like:

If $(B,\mathcal{B})$ is a measurable space then $\mu_n\to\mu$ if $\mu_n(A)\to\mu(A)$ for every $A\subseteq B$?

Are there examples where say, $\int_Bf \, d\mu_n\to\int_Bf \, d\mu$ but $\mu_n(A)\to\mu(A)$ fails?

Comment: I think examples where $\int_Bf \, d\mu_n\to\int_Bf \, d\mu$ but $\mu_n(A) \to \mu(A)$ fails do exist, _if_ you construe $\int_Bf \, d\mu_n\to\int_Bf \, d\mu$ as holding for just one function $f$.  You need that to be true of a sufficiently broad class of functions before you can say $\mu_n(A) \to \mu(A)$ for _every_ measurable set $A$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Of course μn(A)→μ(A) is the same as $\int \chi_A d\mu _n \to \int \chi_A d\mu $

Comment: The example is a a sequence of delta, $\mu_n=\delta_{1/n}$, and $\mu=\delta_0$, with $A=(0,1)$. The problem is that probability can go at boundary of the set A, and requiring convergence for all measurable set would be to strong. Indeed weak convergence is equivalent to $\mu_n(A) \to \mu(A)$ only for sets A such that their boundary has zero $\mu$-measure.

Comment: Thanks for the example Kolmo. I see now why it is natural to test against functions.